# How to Enable TLSv1.2 in Jenkins for SMTP

Tags: email, ssl, jenkins, tls1.2

While working on enabling emails for jenkins, I met with an issue that blocked me for almost 4 days.

Issue : Emails sent out from jenkins using SMTP server were not working and error log showed issues with authenticating certificates.

After several tries with certificate rotation, updating private keys etc , this issue stumped me beyond my expectation.

Below is the resolution if it may help someone in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jenkins configuration was changed so that the JAVA_ARGS looked like below:

JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2"

To resolve the issue, the following steps were performed:

- Edit out the Jenkins configuration file (in Ubuntu, generally it is located at /etc/default/Jenkins) and add the arguments as highlighted above. (Ensure that you add both highlighted parameters!)
- Restart the Jenkins service by typing in “service Jenkins restart”
- Now open Jenkins Dashboard on your favorite browser and then navigate to – Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification.
- Click on the Advanced button.
- Ensure that “Use SSL” option is not selected – it needs to stay unchecked.
- Hit the Save button. Email now works over TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 0):

For Centos the jenkins file path is
**/etc/sysconfig/jenkins**

for Ubuntu the jenkins file path is
**/etc/default/jenkins**

Add the following line to use the TLS version 1.2

In my case the old line was,
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

I have replaced by below line,

**JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2"**

**Now save and close the file.**

Restart the Jenkins service by following command,
**service Jenkins restart**

Now open Jenkins Dashboard on your favorite browser and then navigate to –
**Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification.**

Click on the Advanced button.

Ensure that “Use SSL” option is not selected – it needs to stay unchecked.

Hit the Save button. Email now works over TLSv1.2.

To check the Jenkins is using the TLSv1.2 use below command.

**openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect :**

Note: kindly replace the SMTP hostname and Port. To get those details go to manage jenkins > configure system > SMTP server details

The command output will have

**SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.2**